# Unable to scroll down in android with appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, scroll, appium

Appium version: 1.4.0.0

OS: Windows 7

Library: android.AndroidDriver

selenium.WebDriver

I'm using Java for automation with Appium

I have tried following code.

```
driver.swipe(381, 783, 364, 218, 3000);
driver.scrollTo("Confirm");
driver.scrollToExact("Confirm");
```

Error when use scrollto: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

Error when use swipe: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: did you Override the scrollTo method for the driver? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to swipe vertically in IOS:

```
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize(); 

int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);

//Find endy point which is at top side of screen. 
int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20); 

//Find horizontal point where you wants to swipe. It is in middle of screen width. 
int startx = size.width / 2; 

//Swipe from Bottom to Top. 
driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 3000); 
makeWait(2);
```

hope it will help u.

Answer (score 0):

Have created a function to swipe(wrapped)

```
 public void scroll() throws IOException {
              try {
                Dimension dimensions = driver.manage().window().getSize();
                System.out.println("Size of Window= " +dimensions);
                int scrollStart = (int) (dimensions.getHeight() * 0.5);
                System.out.println("Size of scrollStart= " +scrollStart);
                int scrollEnd = (int) (dimensions.getHeight() * 0.2);
                System.out.println("Size of cscrollEnd= " + scrollEnd);             
                driver.swipe(0,scrollStart,0,scrollEnd,1000);           

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                }

          }
```

add this to ur code and simply use `scroll();` in ur test case

Comment: Am I using the correct jar file? "java-client-2.1.0.jar"?

Comment: i got the same error with previous code 
driver.swipe(381, 783, 364, 218, 3000);
Im using  
WebDriver driver;
 AndroidDriver drivers;

Comment: I dont think ur using my code properly..since its workin in mine..can u post ur whole code and how ur running the script

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll down using screen coordinates:

```
public void scrollDown() {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int x = size.width / 2;
    int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.60);
    int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.10);
    driver.swipe(x, starty, x, endy, 2000);
}
```